# React Native Grid Issues (iOS)

Tags: react-native

While rendering a grid of items on iOS there is a small white gap I can't get rid of.Works fine on Android.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i41S.png)

I'm using Dimensions to get the width and then apply '/ 3' to each 'cell/item'.

I believe the proper styles are applied to contentContainerStyle of the Listview so not sure what is it that I'm missing.

```
renderUser(user) {
        var userElement = <View style={{
        width:WidthHeight.size.width / 3,
        position:'relative',
        height:100,
        backgroundColor:'transparent',
        flexDirection:'column',
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
        }} >

<Image source={{ uri: user.picture.large}} resizeMode={"cover"} style={{ position:'absolute', flex:1, top:0, left:0, bottom:0, right:0, height:100,  }} />

<TouchableOpacity onPress={Actions.conversation} style={{ flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center' }} activeOpacity={75 / 100}>  
  <Bold style={{ alignSelf:'stretch', fontSize:45, fontWeight:'900', color:'#fff', }} > {user.match} </Bold> 
  <Bold  style={{ fontSize:13,  color:'#fff', }}> {user.name.first.toUpperCase()} </Bold>  
</TouchableOpacity>

    </View>

  return userElement;

}

render() {
return (
  <View style={Containers.containerNavbar}>

    <ListView
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'flex-start'
        }}
      initialListSize={30}
      pageSize={60}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderUser.bind(this)}
    />

  </View>
);
}
```

Any insights ? TIA

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you have to account for fractions? I.e. if total width is 10, then make the col widths 3,3,4 (instead of 3.33,3.33,3.33)

Comment: I need equal width columns ;)